# Excel: Create new row and interpolate

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for an Excel macro that is able to go through column A (Time) and create a new row where every whole number should be. After a new row is created, the values for column D and E need to be interpolated for that new row. The row should also be highlighted. Finally all highlighted rows should be hidden (this can be done by filter by cell color).

The biggest problem I am coming up with is when to insert a new row since it isn't always the same amount of rows in between. I've thought about comparing the cells in adjacent rows, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Below is an image to help explain what I need. (minus the hidden rows)[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASiuf.png)

Comment: `if int(.cells(i, "A").value2) <> int(.cells(i + 1, "A").value2) then `

Comment: I have done this exactly with cubic splines. Too complex for your solution. Try using `VLOOKUP()` and `FORECAST()` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code for your "Biggest Problem" .... I'm not sure what math you want for the "interpolated" part:

```
Sub Insert_whole_Number_row()
    C = 1
    R = ActiveCell.Row
    If Cells(R, C) = "" Then Exit Sub
    Do Until Cells(R, C) = ""
        If Int(Cells(R, C)) <> Int(Cells(R + 1, C)) Then
            Rows(R + C).Insert
            R = R + 1
            Cells(R, C) = Int(Cells(R + 1, C))
            Range(Cells(R, C), Cells(R, C + 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Loop
    MsgBox "Done...."
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mike! I added an ElseIf to not create a new row in the case the time data was already a whole number. The interpolation should be in the form of y=y1+(x-x1)*((y2-y1)/x2-x1)). In the photo in the first post it is shown as the selected cell. 

I tried using Range.Formula and Range.FormulaR1C1 to do this. I couldn't find out how to reference a certain cell while writing out the formula.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Not a VBA solution, but an Excel one

[image: pic]

1. Make a table with the whole number values you want to use (cell 'E3' and below)
2. Find the row of the nearest number `index=MATCH(E3,$B$3:$B$105)`
3. Get the previous and next `t` values `t1=INDEX($B$3:$B$105, $F3)` and `t2=INDEX($B$3:$B$105, $F3+1)`
4. Get the previous and next `x` values `x1=INDEX($C$3:$C$105, $F3)` and `t2=INDEX($C$3:$C$105, $F3+1)`
5. Interpolate the `x` values `x=FORECAST(E3,I3:J3,G3:H3)`